# Schematic for dual fixtures/wiring

Tags: wiring

Two light fixtures controlled from four different locations using three way and four way switches; the feed is at the first light fixture.

Comment: Need more info of what you are trying to do.

Comment: @WarLoki They are trying to turn on two lights, from four locations.

Answer (score 1):

The basic wiring would look something like this.

[image: switch type labeled]

Since code requires a grounded (neutral) conductor at each switch, you'll have to carry it through all the way to the last switch.  Because of this, the cables between the switches will need an extra conductor.

You'll have to pull 14/3 with ground between the light and the first switch box. Then you'll pull either 14/4 with ground if you can find it, or 14/2/2 with ground between each switch location .

***NOTE:*** If this is a 20 ampere circuit, use 12 AWG conductors instead of 14 AWG.

[image: cable type labeled]

The first and last switches will be 3-way, while the two in the middle will be 4-way switches.

[image: switch type labeled]

Adding more lights is as simple as tapping off of the wires that connect to the first light.

[image: include extra light]

***NOTE:*** Grounding conductors are not shown in the diagrams, make sure all devices and enclosures are properly grounded.

Comment: The crayon is a nice touch!